# node.js architectural advice on avoiding global state

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, design-patterns, global

I am working on a small hobby project, where I would really like some input and advice.

This is my first "real" node project, and I hope it will teach me a lot about node.js development. I am a .net developer by day, and have been for about 15 years professionally. I have had periods of doing Java as well. I have created small node.js projects to be used as micro services.

But this project can no longer be classified as a micro service ;-)

The purpose of the project is to sample some sensor data, and do some reporting. An idea I got from playing around with a PLC at university. I do that by sampling from a PLC, and emitting the data using ZeroMQ. My node.js server then listens for this sensor data, and stores it in a MongoDB.

I expose that data in a REST api. The REST api also exposes resources like batches and other stuff like authentication etc. On top of that I have an AngularJS app, that creates defines the UI.

The one thing that really annoys me, is that I want to globally assign what batch is running. I have a collection of batches, and one of them is the running one. There are a two ways I see to do this, and both illustrate my novice status in the node.js world. All users should be able to see what batch is running, and I want to be able to easily tell from anywhere in the code as well.

1) Set a flag on the object in Mongo. This has a number of problems. The obvious one being performance. I receive sensor data 10 times a second, and I don't want to ask the database every time what batch to save it under.

2) Save the info on the global object. I really don't like this either. I don't like global state in my code.

What is a good pattern for doing something like this? Does my question make any sense?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Way too broad. Please come back with specific questions and please only tag to the point of the architecture you are addressing. You honestly might find more love for "kicking around" design concepts on [programmers.stackexchange.com/](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) where a bit more chat is tolerated. Or you can ask a specific question here instead as well.

Comment: Hmmm perhaps you're right... mostly interested how to handle global objects when I think about it. Will try to refine the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a simple REST call to **set** the active batch and call it inside the batch when is started up and ready to accept requests. For example:

```
app.put('/active-batch', function(req, res, next){
    // Make sure req.body is defined
    app.set('active-batch', req.body);
    res.end();
});
```

Then everywhere in the code you can use:

```
app.get('active-batch');
```

The [app.set](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.set) let you save data globally accessible in your app and [app.get](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.get) let you read previously stored data.

Comment: I am very open to people wanting help but does this **really** answer the question? And more to the point "Which" of the several questions asked are you actually answering? Glad you want to help or get ahead or whatever. But some things you should just really leave alone.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I just wanted to help providing a solution of what I could understood. Do I need to remove this answer till the question is well formed?

Comment: Well it really just my opinion, but I think the "question" asks for more than what you have responded with and is generally too broad in doing so. So you can either consider this to be a reasonable answer or risk the downvotes that may come as a result of it not really answering what was asked. It's your choice really, but there generally is a reason why you find questions left unanswered, especially where the existing comments point to that reason. Up to you.

Comment: Thanks! I read again the question and I think it may answer, so this time I'll want to take that risk :)